# Showing Duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name tblnetworkstatus and I have 11 columns

```
Id
issue_name
affected_server
affected_service
issue_type
priority
duration
status
start_date
end_date
description
```

I am getting id in affected_server and affected_service which I am storing in my DB, now I have three situations

```
Either both affected_server and affected_service has been selected
Only affected_server is selected
Only affected_service is selected
```

I am getting the name of affected_server and affected_service from tblserver and tblproducts respectively using join on three tables tblnetworkstatus,tblserver and tblproduct I already have the following query got from here

```
SELECT 
    m.issue_name ,m.issue_type ,
    m.priority ,m.status,m.description ,
    m.start_date,m.end_date,m.duration,
    s.name  as server_name,p.name as product_name
    from mod_networkstatus as m 
    LEFT JOIN  tblservers as  s  ON  FIND_IN_SET(s.id,m.affected_server)
    LEFT JOIN tblproducts as  p  ON  FIND_IN_SET(p.id,m.affected_service)
```

But If I have multiple id's of affected_server and affected_service like I am storing 1,2,3,4 in a single column affected_server or affected_service and I am getting the record duplicate instead only the affected_server or affetced_service is different in that which I don't want I want to show these in a single coulmn field after retrieving like storing 1,2,3,4  then how can I do that?

tblproducts structure

```
Column        Type      Null    
id            int(10)   No       
type          text      No       
gid           int(10)   No       
name          text      No       
description   text      No
```

tblserver structure

```
Column       Type      Null 
id           int(10)   No        
name         text      No        
ipaddress    text      No        
assignedips  text      No        
hostname     text      No
```

table mod_network_status

```
Column               Type           Null    Default     
id                   int(11)        No       
issue_name           varchar(15)    No       
affected_server      varchar(150)   No       
affected_service     varchar(150)   Yes     NULL     
issue_type           varchar(20)    Yes     NULL     
priority             varchar(20)    Yes     NULL     
duration             varchar(20)    Yes     NULL     
status               varchar(20)    Yes     NULL     
start_date           datetime       Yes     NULL     
end_date             datetime       Yes     NULL     
description          varchar(200)   Yes     NULL     


issue_name       issue_type     server_name     product_name    
service_failure  maintenance    server1         hosting account
service_failure  maintenance    osrstrust       hosting account
test             failure        vpn             HOME USER
```

Now look the above result it gives me the perfect record see row2 in which everything is same instead of server name only I want this on row1 like that server1,osrstrust

Comment: Can You give us table structure for all three tables affected_server, tblservers, tblproducts?

Comment: @DeepakNirala I have edited check it

Comment: Table - mod_networkstatus?

Comment: Don't store CSVs. See normalisation

Comment: @Strawberry kindly explain in detial

Comment: No. That's what google is for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you three things:

1. You need to restructure your table **mod_network_status**

   ```
   Column               Type           Null    Default     
   id                   int(11)        No       
   issue_name           varchar(15)    No       
   server_id            varchar(150)   No       
   service_id           varchar(150)   Yes     NULL     
   issue_type           varchar(20)    Yes     NULL     
   priority             varchar(20)    Yes     NULL     
   duration             varchar(20)    Yes     NULL     
   status               varchar(20)    Yes     NULL     
   start_date           datetime       Yes     NULL     
   end_date             datetime       Yes     NULL     
   description          varchar(200)   Yes     NULL
   ```
2. You need to understand how to use Left Join Ref : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html
3. **FIND_IN_SET** is string function but you are using id(int). Syntax FIND_IN_SET (search string, string list)

Comment: I have just suggested you this table. You may modify this based on your requirement.

Comment: But it's working and giving me the fine result using FIND_IN_SET Check my Edit again the result of the query